# Undefined reference while compiling (compiler flag problem)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I am working on a project where I use google protobuffers. I am currently stuck at the compilation of the program in the CLion IDE. Everytime I compile with WSL, the following errors occur:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/***/Documents/***/Protobuf_examples/data.pb.cc:146: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/***/Documents/***/Protobuf_examples/data.pb.cc:154: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
```

There are certain compiler flags needed for a successful compilation. Whenever I compile from a linux subsystem everything works with the following command:

```
c++ main.cpp data.pb.h data.pb.cc -o proto -pthread -I/usr/local/include -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotoc -lprotobuf -lpthread
```

I can run my program and it runs perfectly fine. However, I would like the debug capabilities of the Clion IDE.

I tried putting in the compiler flags in the CMake file. It looks like this:

(Edit: Per request the image is now in text)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(Protobuf)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-pthread -I/usr/local/include -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotoc -lprotobuf -lpthread")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )

add_executable(Protobuf main.cpp data.pb.h data.pb.cc)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: As for your problem, you need to learn the difference between *compiling* source files to object files, and *linking* objects files and libraries to create the executable. The error you get is because you do not link with the libraries. Instead you pass the linker flags to the compiler, which doesn't use them. Read about the CMake [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of "Some programmer dude" its clear that this is **not** a compiler issue but a linker issue. Therefore putting linker flags into the compiler flags results in it not operating.

Thanks to DevSolar I made some more changes to the CMake and it now looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(Protobuf)

include(FindProtobuf)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-pthread -I/usr/local/include -pthread")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )

add_executable(Protobuf main.cpp data.pb.h data.pb.cc)

target_link_libraries(Protobuf ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

By using the find_package and include_directories, I am now able to link the protobuf library without any compiler-specific flags.

Comment: Very nice edit. Note that `FindThreads.cmake` allows similar things for PThreads.